# Is this grammar LL(1) grammar?

Tags: grammar

Is this grammar LL(1)? Would it be a problem that `S` can be both `E/S` and `E`?

```
S -> E / S 
S -> E
E -> letter 
E -> ‘ S ’
```

Can it derive `‘a / e / ‘g / s’ ’ / q` like this?

```
S =>  E / S 
  => ‘S’ / S 
  => ‘E / S’ / S 
  => ‘a / S’/ S
  => ‘a / E / S’ / S
  => ‘a / E / ‘E / S’’ / S
  => ‘a / e / ‘g / s’’ / q
```

Comment: Is this question a HOMEWORK question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1095332: If you decide to migrate a question from one SE site to another one, as you have done here, please please delete the question from the original site. [We prefer that the same question not be active on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Thanks very much.

Comment: @einpoklum The question deals with software algorithms and tools (parsing, parser generators) commonly used by programmers. On the other hand, it's almost certainly homework.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't see a relevant difference between the questions "Will this tool accept this grammar?" and "Does this grammar satisfy these properties?". But I do understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a grammar `G` is `LL(1)` if and only if whenever `A → u` and `A → v` are distinct productions in `G`, the following conditions hold:

1. For no terminal `a` do `u` and `v` derive strings beginning with `a`.
2. At most one of `u` and `v` derive the empty string `λ`
3. If `u ⇒* λ` then `v` does not derive any strings beginning with a terminal in `FOLLOW(A)`.

The second and third conditions are trivial because no sequence of terminal and nonterminal symbols derive the empty string in your grammar. Now consider the productions `S → E / S` and `S → E`. Can you find two derivations `S ⇒ E / S ⇒* au` and `S ⇒ E ⇒* av` where `a` is a terminal that violate the first condition? This question is obviously homework, so I will leave answering this question to you.